# what is the reason to have <header> <footer> tags in html5

Tags: css, html, header, footer

why to use     tags in html5 even though we can achieve that functionality by html4  by adding css styles,
Other than every technology with latest version will have more flexibility or features. please help me to understand..

Comment: The main reason is semantics.

Comment: Tags improve your seo, meaning your ranking on search enginges (like Google, Bing, Yahoo etc.) will improve, if you use them correctly.

Comment: Also helps with accessibility (if used correctly) as screen readers can identify the type of content to the user (such as allowing them to go directly to navigation blocks without a "skip to nav" link).

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage is while loading your code the web browser knows the header and footer portion. It helps in prioritizing on the things to be loaded first and which has to be loaded later. In addition this will be much easily understood by a Google Bot or a screen reader due to its logical markup.

Answer (score -2):

As @panther wrote, the main reason is semantics. Also it's better for search engines to use html5. You can achieve a lot of tags using some css, for example adding `display: inline` to `div` will give you `span` etc

Comment: It won't give you an actual `span`, but a `div` that _behaves_ like a `span`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I wrote it in wrong words